# how to format `20134859` into `20 - 13:48:59`

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

Is there any nice (maybe one line) way how to format

`20134859` into `20 - 13:48:59` ??

I started with `"20134859".unpack('a2a*').join(' - ')` but I don't know how to tackle the `:` I was thinking if or how I can split and join(':') the second element that is return from unpack. All in one line.

this works but I am sure there is out there something I'll like more

```
s = "20134859"
"#{s[0,2]} - #{s[2,2]}:#{s[4,2]}:#{s[6,2]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> "%s - %s:%s:%s"%"20134859".unpack('a2'*4)
=> "20 - 13:48:59"
```

Or with `scan` borrowed from DigitalRoss

```
irb(main):002:0> "%s - %s:%s:%s"%"20134859".scan(/../)
=> "20 - 13:48:59"
```

Comment: Heh, interesting. I would not have thought of this one.

Comment: I like that I can choose from two great answers here. Could you explain why `a2` is enclosed in apostrophe?

Comment: @Radek, as opposed to double quotes? Just lazy inconsistency

Comment: So, does it mean 4 times 'a2'?

Answer (score 2):

I like your answer best, but you might like to try the `%` operator on strings and see if you like that better.  Just a thought.  It does make the overall format string more apparent.

Comment: I.e., `"%2d - %2d:%2d:%2d" % [s[0,2],s[2,2],s[4,2],s[6,2]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
'20134859'.scan(/../).join(':').sub ':',' - '
```